# ruby 'gsub' to snake case

Tags: ruby, regex

The following code from a book is supposed to transfer `"FOO92OBAR"` to `"FOO92_O_BAR"`:

```
gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/, '\1_\2')
```

Can anyone explain how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([a-z\d])` looks for a lowercase letter (a-z) or a number (`\d` means a digit). The () around the whole thing assign the result to regex subgroup 1.
`([A-Z])` then looks for an uppercase letter, assigning the result to group 2. So the whole thing looks for a lowercase-or-digit followed by an uppercase letter. The second part, `'\1_\2'`, means "regex group 1 followed by regex group 2"

gsub replaces every time it sees a lowercase-or-digit followed by an uppercase letter with (the first thing)_(the second thing).

So actually `FOO92OBAR` will be  `FOO92_OBAR`.

For `FOO92OBAR` to become  `FOO92_O_BAR`, the replace part should be `'\1_\2_'` (since only the `O` is the second part.. `BAR` is not matched, so not replaced at all).

Comment: How does [a-z\d] match FOO92? shouldn't it match foo92 (small case) ?

Comment: It only matches the 2. ` [a-z\d]` is one character in that range.
Everything that is not matches is not replaced, just as if you replace all a's by b's, everything that is not an "a" is not touched.

Answer (score 1):

It works using [regular expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm).

The two parameters of gsub are the match expression and the replacement. Because the match `/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/` contains groups (identified by `(...)`), then you can reference a match in the replacement using `\ID` where the ID is the number of the group, starting from 1.

That said, the code `gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/, '\1_\2')`

```
# take any combination of
([a-z\d])([A-Z])

# which means any combinations of a (1) lower-case char or (2) digit
([a-z\d])
# followed by an (1) upper case letter
([A-Z])

# if any, replace it with
\1_\2

# that represents the first group
\1
# followed by _
# followed by the second group
\2
```

Please note that your example will generate `FOO92_OBAR`, not `FOO92_O_BAR`

```
2.1.5 :001 > string = "FOO92OBAR"
 => "FOO92OBAR"
2.1.5 :002 > string.gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/, '\1_\2')
 => "FOO92_OBAR"
```

The explanation is because there is only one case of a "lower-case char or digit" (and that is a digit) followed by an upper case char.

```
2.1.5 :003 > string.scan(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/)
 => [["2", "O"]]
```

Regular expressions are case sensitive by default.